# Repeat rows based on item count for each row and assign values for repeated rows

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, random, pivot

I have a df with the item and it is available in different rooms

```
  Item     Room1  Room2  Room3  Room4
  Ball      1       1     1        0
  Bat       1       1     1        1
  Wicket    1       1     1        0
```

Now I want to repeat the rows based on item counts on different Rooms. For example for Item - Ball there are three 1's in Room1, Room2, Room3 so need to repeat 3 rows with assigning 0 in each row only for Room1, Room2, Room3 columns, and Room4 is not considered for Item Ball and it can be 0's for all Ball item rows. There are 300 columns with different room names, for example Room1,room2,room3,room4,BlockArea1,Block2 etc.Below is the expected output

```
  Item     Room1  Room2  Room3  Room4
  Ball      1       1     1        0
  Ball      1       0     1        0
  Ball      1       1     0        0 
  Bat       1       1     1        1
  Bat       1       1     1        0
  Bat       1       1     0        1
  Bat       1       0     1        1
  Wicket    1       1     1        0
  Wicket    1       0     1        0
  Wicket    1       1     0        0
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the logic behind the rows that do not get 0? (e.g first rows of Ball and Wicket of expected output) when you said: _assigning 0 in each row only for Room1, Room2, Room3 columns_

Comment: Based on row counts need to assign zero only for Room1, Room2, Room3. If Ball is having 3 1's then need to assign 0 to only one of the columns.

Comment: Ball has 3 1s, so shouldn't the first row of expected output's Room1 must be 0 not 1?

Comment: Finally for Ball there should be 4 rows, Need to retain the original row as it is and for repeated 3 rows for one of the column make it 0 and remaining 2 columns can be 1

Comment: In your expected output, there are only 3 rows for `Ball`, including the original row?

Comment: @QuangHoang, I wanted to later merge with the input data frame. So, did not include that in the expected output. Both are fine for me.

Comment: What I’m trying to say is why only 3 **including the original**

Comment: @QuangHoang Can I change the original post with the expected output byincluding the original row?

Comment: @QuangHoang: is it clear? or do I need to provide more information. Plz let me know

Comment: I understand what you want. However, you **already** include the originals in the expected output, and still only three rows for `Ball`. That’s why people are confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228349/discussion-between-jethen-and-quang-hoang).

Answer (score 1):

To have a more interesting example, with a source row containing *0*
somewhere else than in the last column, I created *df* as:

```
     Item  Room1  Room2  Room3  Room4
0    Ball      1      1      1      0
1     Bat      1      1      1      1
2  Wicket      1      1      1      0
3    Xxxx      0      1      1      1
```

The first step is to define a function to process each row:

```
def rowProc(row):
    n = 0
    res = []
    for idx, val in row[row > 0].items():
        outRow = row.copy()
        if n > 0:
            outRow[idx] = 0
        res.append(outRow)
        n += 1
    return pd.DataFrame(res)
```

An important project detail is that the source row comes here from
a bit "changed" DataFrame, namely *Item* column will be set as
the index. So the only processed columns are "further" (*Room...*)
columns.

For the current row it generates a DataFrame containing:

- as many rows as how many ones contains the source row,
- the first output row is an exact copy of the source row (like in
  your expected result),
- further rows have consecutive ones set to *0*.

Then run:

```
result = pd.concat(df.set_index('Item').apply(rowProc, axis=1).tolist())
result.index.name = 'Item'
result.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
      Item  Room1  Room2  Room3  Room4
0     Ball      1      1      1      0
1     Ball      1      0      1      0
2     Ball      1      1      0      0
3      Bat      1      1      1      1
4      Bat      1      0      1      1
5      Bat      1      1      0      1
6      Bat      1      1      1      0
7   Wicket      1      1      1      0
8   Wicket      1      0      1      0
9   Wicket      1      1      0      0
10    Xxxx      0      1      1      1
11    Xxxx      0      1      0      1
12    Xxxx      0      1      1      0
```